# How to suppress runtime questions while changing file permission in unix

Tags: shell, unix, plsql

We calling a PLSQL program unit from shell script, and the PLSQL program unit writes a file in database file system mount location with 644 permission. And then finally the shell script attempts to change the file permission mode to 764 using below statement.

```
chmod 764 $file
```

During run time, script is requesting for user input to change the file permission.

```
override mode 644 on /path/to/file/filename?
```

How to suppress this or is there any way to provide 'Y' in the chmod command itself ?

Comment: I'm not sure that the PL/SQL component is significant in this question.

Answer (score 2):

To suppress [chmod](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/chmod.htm) messages you can add `-f` flag as:

```
 chmod  -f 764 $file
```

> -f, --silent, --quiet  suppress most error messages